# Get every ID of images by class name

Tags: javascript

I and trying to use JavaScript to get the ID of every image on a page that has the CSS class 'asset' and assign the IDs to a new array.

I can get all the images using below, but I need the IDs into a new array.

```
var image_ids = document.getElementsByClassName("asset");
```

Comment: How have you tried getting the ids?

Comment: I can get the first ID using the code below, but I need them all and in an array: `var image_ids = document.getElementsByClassName("asset")[0].id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, especially for IE9 in the end:

```
    var imageClassList = document.getElementsByClassName("asset");
    var imageIdList = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, n = imageClassList.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var el = imageClassList[i];
        if (el.id) { imageIdList.push(el.id); }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

How about `Array.from`?

```
const ids = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName("asset"),
  ({ id }) => id
);
```

Comment: Ahh that works, but do you know if that code has any compatibility issues with older browsers, specifically IE9 onwards?

Comment: That's what build tools like Babel are for, and polyfills - they let you keep your source code in the most readable and recent form of the language, while continuing to allow obsolete browsers to understand the production code.

Comment: Totally agree, but am using it in the context of a HTML5 banner, so can't call in any extra code or polyfills in this instance.

Comment: Sure you can - properly transpiled code will work with any browser. The resulting script will contain (eg) `var`s instead of `const` and `let`, `function`s instead of arrow functions (with the appropriate references to `this`), and (for example) something that defines `Array.from` if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: Of course, you're free to write it in ES5 if you want, but for any script that isn't completely trivial, I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 2):

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns an iterable, you can use the spread operator:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('asset')].map(({id}) => id);
```

Comment: Ahh this works also, but throws an error in IE9. Do you know of a more compatible code snippet with this browser? Thanks.